# How can I call same class twice using super() in other class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I got class Z which has 5 attributes:

- ID
- actual x
- actual y
- future x
- future y

actual x and actual y I can replace using Position class(using class inheritance). The problem is that I want to replace future position using same method. How can I do it to avoid namespace conflict? Do I really need to create new Position class with slightly changed namespace ?

I know I can do (but i dont like this solution):

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self,x , y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Position2:
    def __init__(self,x , y):
        self.fx = x
        self.fy = y

class Z(Position,Position2):
    def __init__(self, x, y, f_x, f_y, Id):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        super().__init__(f_x,f_y)
        self.Id = Id
```

actual code:

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self,x , y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Z(Position):
    def __init__(self, x, y, f_x, f_y, Id):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.Id = Id
```

I would like to get something like:

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self,x , y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Z(Position):
    def __init__(self, x, y, f_x, f_y, Id):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        super().__init__(f_x, f_y)
        self.Id = Id
```

that I could easy print actual and future parameters.

Comment: What is `Z`? Is it a thing with two positions? or a Position with two positions?

Comment: why are you even trying to use inheritance here? Just use composition

Comment: i wanted to do it neatly/clearly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for composition rather than inheritance.  Position is a concept. You have a class that references two positions:

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y

class Z:
    def __init__(self, x, y, fx, fy, id):
        self.p = Position(x, y)
        self.fp = Position(fx, fy)
        self.id = id
```

You should only inherit from `Position` if you want `Z` to have access to the behavior of `Position`. If that were the case, you could either define `fx` and `fy` as attributes of `Z`, or use composition as before:

```
class Z(Position):
    def __init__(self, x, y, fx, fx, id):
        super.__init__(x, y)
        self.fx = fx
        self.fy = fy
        self.id = id
```

Or

```
class Z(Position):
    def __init__(self, x, y, fx, fx, id):
        super.__init__(x, y)
        self.fp = Position(fx, fy)
        self.id = id
```

By the way, if your `Position` class is really just a simple container, consider using [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to hold the values. For example:

```
Position = namedtuple('Position', ['x', 'y'])
```

This version of `Position` inherits from the built in `tuple`, so it is much more efficient at storing values.

Answer (score 0):

why not list in Position constructor,

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self,x , y):
        self.x_lst.append(x)
        self.y_lst.append(y)

class Z(Position):
    def __init__(self, x, y, f_x, f_y, Id):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        super().__init__(f_x, f_y)
        self.Id = Id
```

x_lst and y_lst are lists. 
Not sure if this idea works for you.

Comment: You'll get an AttributeError if you try to run this. `x_lst` and `y_lst` need to be defined.

Comment: second init accesses the same class, he has mult inheritence here

Comment: @snamef. Multiple inheritance is when your class inserts from two classes. This only inherits from one. `__init__` is just a regular method in this context, and you can call it as often as you want. The second call just overwrites the attributes set by the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call Type.**init**(self,args) for a parent class init

```
class First(object):
def __init__(self, x):
    print ("First(): entering")
    self. x = x
    print ("First(): exiting")

class Second(object):
    def __init__(self , y ):
        print ("Second(): entering")
        self. y = y
        print ("Second(): exiting")

class Third(First, Second):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        print ("Third(): entering")
        First.__init__(self,x)
        Second.__init__(self,y)
        #super(Third, self).__init__(x,y)
        print ("Third(): exiting")

def __repr__(self):

    return f'{self.x} { self.y}'



a = Third(10,20)

print(a)
```

Comment: OP has a solution with three classes but stated they did not want the third class.

Comment: This is a correct solution (excerpt the indentation), but does not capture the concept of OP's intent.